# Работа функции filter с экземплярами класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, list, filter

Есть класс `Employee`, от которого созданы несколько экземпляров.
Необходимо, используя функцию **filter**, получить список имен служащих, имеющих оценки ниже 5.

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, name, mark):
        self.name = name
        self.mark = mark

empl1 = Employee('Kate', 3)
empl2 = Employee('Lena', 4) 
empl3 = Employee('Natasha', 2)
empl4 = Employee('Liza', 1) 
empl5 = Employee('Vera', 5) 
empl6 = Employee('Valentina', 6)

my_list = [empl1, empl2, empl3, empl4, empl5, empl6] 

result = [filter(lambda el, el.mark < 5), my_list]
```

В списке result будут отобраны экземпляры класса, отвечающих заданному условию.
***Вопрос.*** Можно ли модифицировать последнюю строку так, чтобы в списке оказались имена служащих?

Answer (score 7):

Можно так:

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, name, mark):
        self.name = name
        self.mark = mark

empl1 = Employee('Kate', 3)
empl2 = Employee('Lena', 4) 
empl3 = Employee('Natasha', 2)
empl4 = Employee('Liza', 1) 
empl5 = Employee('Vera', 5) 
empl6 = Employee('Valentina', 6)

my_list = [empl1, empl2, empl3, empl4, empl5, empl6] 
result = [el.name for el in filter(lambda el: el.mark < 5, my_list)]
```

в результате:

```
>>> result
['Kate', 'Lena', 'Natasha', 'Liza']
```

Comment: Лучше тогда полностью без filter обойтись, так компактнее будет: `[el.name for el in my_list if el.mark <5]`

Comment: @insolor согласен, но у тс в тексте - "используя функцию filter"...

Answer (score 6):

`filter` только фильтрует. Если из каждого элемента нужно вытащить поле имени, то к каждому элементу  уже отфильтрованной последовательности с помощью функции `map` нужно применить лямбду (или другую функцию), которая вытащит это поле:

```
result = list(map(lambda el: el.name, filter(lambda el: el.mark < 5, my_list)))
```

Или через `attrgetter` вместо лямбды:

```
from operator import attrgetter

result = list(map(attrgetter("name"), filter(lambda el: el.mark < 5, my_list)))
```

Вообще, если полностью переписать через list comprehension, в данном случае будет более компактно и читаемо:

```
result = [el.name for el in my_list if el.mark < 5]
```